# UIButton click event not firing due other subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

On my `SplashScreenViewController`, I have a series of sequenced animations that hide and display views via cross-dissolves. There is also a button that is present throughout to allow the user to skip out of this. However, the button is not responding to its touch up inside event. If I tap on it rapidly, sometimes I can get it to fire, but rarely.

I assume that this is a result of what I am doing to the other `UIViews` and that the touch is being absorbed by them.

Each of the other subviews has `User Interaction Enabled` set to `false` (unchecked in the IB). The button is presented last in the IB, which should make it the top view. I also add the following code just in case:

```
_btnAlreadyRegistered.hidden = NO;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:_btnAlreadyRegistered];
_btnAlreadyRegistered.enabled = YES;
```

Here is an example of one of the methods that executes the animation. Each of the various fade in / fade out animations follows this same pattern:

```
- (void) fadeOutHello {

    _btnAlreadyRegistered.hidden = NO;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:_btnAlreadyRegistered];
    _btnAlreadyRegistered.enabled = YES;

    [UIView transitionWithView:[self view]
                      duration:CROSS_FADE_DURATION_3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{_grayView.hidden = YES;}
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){[self fadeInGetRegistered];}
     ];
}
```

Comment: I ran into a problem once where if the UIButton is not large enough it won't accept taps. I don't recall the size, but there is a minimum size a UIButton needs to be.

Comment: Also, try a test where you turn off all the animations and see if that affects the button's tapability.

Comment: @ThomasW - Yes, I had addressed both of those. I made the the height of the button 50 so that I knew it was tall enough to actually receive the text. I also turned off all the animations and then the button fires just like one would expect.

Comment: If you use [view debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html), does your button have unexpected geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`

Comment: Seems to work a bit better. Still not all that responsive. Usually needs 3 or 4 tips before it actually fires. Thanks!